# Funcion para devolver fecha sumando dias JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

necesito hacer una funcion que devuelva la fecha y por parametro poder sumarle X cantidad de dias.
El problema viene cuando los dias que le sumo superan los 31 y ahi deberia sumarle 1 al mes pero como hago para saber que mes tiene 30, 31 o 28 dias?
Por ahora lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
function getDate(days){

    function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = '0' + i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    var hoy = new Date();

    var dd = hoy.getDate()+days;
    var mm = hoy.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = hoy.getFullYear();
        
    dd = addZero(dd);
    mm = addZero(mm);

    var start = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    return start;
}
```

Comment: Mira la libreria [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) tiene muchas funciones que hacen los calculos por ti

Answer (score 2):

Como lo menciona un compañero, puedes usar la librería moment JS! Hay mucho contenido bueno en cuanto a funciones :D ¡Lee su documentación!

```js
var SemanaSiguiente = moment().add(7, 'days');

alert(SemanaSiguiente);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Sin embargo, si lo tuyo es lo nativo de JS, usa esto:

```js
Date.prototype.agregarDias = function(dias) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + dias);
    return date;
}

var fecha = new Date();

//fecha actual + 5 dias
console.log(fecha.agregarDias(5));
```